# How to create generic a ViewModelModule for many classes in Android?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I'm using Dagger2 to inject my `ViewModel` into my fragments. For each fragment I have `ViewModelModule` as below:

```
public abstract class GameViewModelModule {
    @Binds
    abstract ViewModelProvider.Factory bindAppViewModelFactory(AppViewModelFactory factory);

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(GameViewModel.class)
    abstract ViewModel provideGameViewModel(GameViewModel viewModel);
}
```

How can I create a generic class, instead of creating a separate `ViewModelModule` for every fragment?

Comment: Just use the same module for all fragments, one `@Binds` per view model.

Comment: @Nicolas Thanks Nicolas but isn't there any way I can create a generic class?

Comment: No. `@ViewModelKey` has a class parameter, and the only way to use a generic type to get that is to have a reified type, which is only possible for inline functions, not classes. Somewhat unrelated, but what I do is I make a `ViewModelFragment` class that injects itself with the view model factory. That abstracts some code from each of your fragment.

Comment: @Nicolas I'm not sure I understand what you mean through "that injects itself with the view model factory". Can I have/inject generic ViewModel for all classes?

Comment: No, no generics, and unrelated to your question. I was just giving you a tip for reducing the code needed in fragments a little bit. [Here's an example](https://pastebin.com/2uJ0qLKv)

Comment: If you create N `ViewModelProvider.Factory` class for N ViewModel, then you no longer need the map multibinding and you won't need the module.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I'm really confused now. Then how to create a single one?

Comment: Why would you create 1 Factory for N independent ViewModels?  I know Google does that in their example, but even in that case I question why they did it.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I would like to have only one factory that can server my all 10 ViewModels. I don't want to have 10 different classes. Is this even possible?

Comment: It is possible, but it is more complicated, because then you have to create a ViewModelModule for each ViewModel that map-multibinds them into Dagger so that the Factory can return an instance of the exact ViewModel from Dagger's provider based on the ViewModel's class. In fact, you're doing that right now, so if you want 1 Factory, then you need the module, the end.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I udnerstand now, I'll keep my actual structure. I find your information is very useful, I think you should add it as an answer so it can also help others.